# How do I reset the working tree without moving HEAD?

Tags: git

Given a git branch with some commits on it (C is the most recent commit):

```
A -> B -> C
```

How do I reset my workspace so that all the files are in the state they were at commit B, but HEAD is still at C?

I've looked at `git-reset`, but none of the options seem to help. The man page suggests that all the different modes will move HEAD:

> ```
> --soft
>    Does not touch the index file or the working tree at all 
>    (but resets the head to <commit>, just like all modes do).
> ```

I've tried `git reset HEAD~` but that moves HEAD.

Comment: You haven't been selecting answers to many of your questions lately. Any particular reason for that?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Most of them have good answers, so I'll sort it out.

Comment: No worries. I was just wondering.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> `git checkout [-p|--patch] [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>...`
>
> `git checkout with <paths>` or `--patch` is used to restore modified or deleted paths to their original contents from the index or replace paths with the contents from a named `<tree-ish>` (most often a commit-ish).

So you need to run this at root of your repository (works fine for any sub-tree or file(s) too):

```
git checkout HEAD~ -- .
```

This will result in git applying changes necessary to revert files to `HEAD~` state not counting file removals, the changes will be in the index.  Add `--no-overlay` flag to allow removal of files added since `HEAD~`:

```
git checkout --no-overlay HEAD~ -- .
```

From `man git-checkout` (git v2.44.0):

> `--overlay`, `--no-overlay`
> In the default overlay mode, `git checkout` never removes files from the
> index or the working tree. When specifying `--no-overlay`, files that appear
> in the index and working tree, but not in `<tree-ish>` are removed, to make
> them match `<tree-ish>` exactly.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, if you want to go back to a different SHA you can replace `HEAD~`, i.e. `git checkout A -- .`

Comment: This doesn't remove files that were added since HEAD~

Comment: @Pod, correct. `git clean` can remove untracked files, but be careful with it, it can remove files you want to keep.

Comment: @xaizek `git clean` doesn't do the trick when you are using the `git checkout` approach. Files added in `HEAD` will not be removed since you are still on the `HEAD`.

Comment: @PinGu, that's true, not sure why I thought about untracked files.  Updated the answer to add `--no-overlay`, thanks.

Answer (score 14):

You could use a combination of hard and soft resets:

```
git reset --hard B
git reset --soft C
```

The first would move `HEAD` to `B` and make all your files look like `B`. The second would then move it back to `C` without changing any files.

This method has the advantage that you are not in a detached-head state and all the differences between `B` and `C` will just show up as inverse diffs of your last actual commit. You will still be on your original branch.

You would probably have to specify `C` as a SHA-1 rather than a ref name, unless you specifically created one for the purpose.

Comment: `HEAD@{1}` should do for `C` instead of a hash.

Comment: Much more explicit than tricky punctuation in accepted answer.

Comment: @DylanYoung `HEAD~ -- .` is somewhat harder to read and copy correctly than `HEAD@{1}`

Comment: This is very clever, and much easier to understand than the accepted answer

Comment: @kylebebak. Thanks. I prefer it to the accepted answer myself.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59956722/21564193) to a similar question, you can use `git restore` for that in Git 2.23+, like so:

```bash
git restore -s HEAD~ .
```

According to its manpage, `git restore`

> [restores] specified paths in the working tree with some contents from a restore source.

You use `-s` (or `--source`) to specify which commit you want to use as the restore source (here `HEAD~`) and specify the path(s) to restore (here everything, so `.`) at the end.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `git checkout`:

```
$ git checkout HEAD~
$ # Or
$ git checkout HEAD^
$ # Or
$ git checkout B
```

This will bring you into a detached head state where the HEAD is detached from a branch.

Comment: Triple ticks don't work on SO unfortunately. Indent by four spaces manually or highlight and click on the `{}` button in the editing toolbar.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Damn it, I'm used to this from github, but thank you!

Comment: No worries. I had the other problem where I kept dreading the manual indentation in GitHub until I figured out the triple ticks.

Comment: I don't want to change HEAD I'm afraid.

Comment: @WilfredHughes The HEAD or the master branch?

Comment: He doesn't want to change the HEAD symbolic ref. He wants the changes from another commit to be present in the working tree, presumably so he can recover that work (e.g. after a tricky rebase).