# Does git have a single command to reset the working tree to HEAD but keep staged changes in index?

Tags: git

I know there are tons of posts on this topic, but I can't seem to find this specific answer.

Obviously, a way to do this would be to `git commit` the staged changes, `git reset --hard HEAD`, then `git reset --soft HEAD~`, then `git add -u`, which is quite verbose.

The default behavior for `reset` is `--mixed` which accomplishes the inverse of what I'm asking for. There certainly has to be a one command solution for this, or at least a better way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove local (untracked) files from the current Git working tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-working-tree)

Comment: Sounds like you want `git stash --keep-index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you are asking for `git stash --keep-index`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. I'll accept your answer in 4 mins. Thank You!

Answer (score 5):

Prior to Git 2.23, no.

In Git 2.23 or later, `git restore` can do the job:

```
git restore -s HEAD
```

Note that `git stash -k` does not do the trick: it leaves the working tree matching the *index*, not the `HEAD` commit.<sup>1</sup>

In all Git versions since 2.5, it may be easier and/or better to use `git worktree add` to create a second work-tree based on the current commit:

```
git worktree add --detach <path> HEAD
```

where `<path>` is wherever you'd like the new work-tree to show up.  This has the advantage of not touching your existing work-tree.  (In Git versions prior to 2.15, I advise doing whatever you are doing in this added work-tree within two weeks, then deleting it, as there's a nasty little bug in those versions of Git regarding added work-trees.  If you're just doing this for the *work-tree files*, the bug itself is harmless, though.)

In versions of Git prior to 2.23, you can do:

```
git stash
# do whatever your job is here, followed by `git reset --hard` if needed
git stash apply --index
git stash drop
```

(or `git stash pop --index`; I just like to keep the apply and drop separate myself).

---

<sup>1</sup>`git stash -k` makes the two stash commits in the usual way, so they are the same as always.  But then, instead of `git reset --hard`, which a regular  non-`-k` `git stash` does, it forcibly adjusts the work-tree to match the stash commit.

The point of `git stash -k` is to allow you to run some sort of test that uses the *work-tree* content, without having to extract the stashed index to another work-tree.  For instance, if you have an automated test system that uses what's in the work-tree, rather than what's in the index, you can `git stash -k`, run the tests, then `git reset --hard` to make the stash applicable again and apply and drop the stash.

Annoyingly, since `git stash` *doesn't* make a stash if the index and work-tree match `HEAD`, `git stash -k` is hard to use to do this kind of automated testing, because there's no guarantee that it actually made a stash.

Comment: I'd just ``stash=`git write-tree`; git reset --hard; git read-tree $stash``, no need to do all the diffing and committing when you just want the index.

Comment: @jthill sure, but that's using commands not aimed at the user. :-) The 2.23+ `git restore` is aimed at users. It might be worth adding as an answer though!

Comment: Yah, I composed it, but looking at it it was so close to a repeat of yours I just added it as a comment instead, I'd already upvoted.  Gonna have to spend some time staring at the new commands, my reaction right now feels a bit too get-off-my-lawn-ish.