# How to soft reset to the previous commit without updating branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'm reviewing PRs locally. For that I'm using IDEA's `Local changes` tab:

[image]

I fetched the branch `PR-35` that points to the PR's commit. Here's how the log looks like:

```
commit 098a7a557b0e59eac036cdf4d53fb396bf184f32 (HEAD -> mr-origin-39, origin/feature/refacto-builder-serializers)
    Adapt environment to support both builds

commit a93eb572d0c522a2dca3bce03c866624b3d56003

    Update README.md
```

Now I can check out the branch `PR-35` and go back 1 commit but preserve  changes introduced by the PR's commit. I can do that using `git reset --soft HEAD~2`:

[image]

It works perfect for me, except that it updates the `PR-35` branch pointer. I want to keep the current branch pointer intact, yet see the changes between the commits. How can I do that?

As a workaround I'm using this for now:

```
$ git checkout mr35
$ mr35=$(git rev-parse --short=5 HEAD)
$ git reset --soft HEAD~1
... (reviewing PR)
$ git reset --hard $mr35
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset the working tree without moving HEAD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40095142/how-do-i-reset-the-working-tree-without-moving-head)

Comment: @NilsWerner, not exactly, because if I run `git checkout HEAD~1 -- .` it indeed shows the changes, but as if they were applied *on top* of the PR's commit, and *not* as if the PR's commit applied changes on top of `HEAD~1` (like `git reset does`).

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi: from your comments it looks like your intention is to review the diff introduced by that PR from your IDE (which is Idea ? correct ?)  Can you please update your question to indicate that ?

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi : is "show the changes in the *Local Changes* tab" a hard requirement ? or is it ok to have the changes displayed in another window ?

Comment: @LeGEC, yeah, because I can have lots of files changed and I want to have the ability to go over the list and then maybe group them etc.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple:

1. Stay on your development branch.
2. Merge PR without auto-committing it by `git merge --no-commit {{PR_BRANCH}}`.
3. View differences by `git diff`.

Now you can decide to commit by `git commit` (message is now not required, it will be generated automatically) or rollback all changes by `git merge --abort`.

Comment: thanks, this could be the option, but I need the files to be in the modified state to be shown in the `Changes` tab of my IDEA.

Comment: As I stated the `--no-commit` option leaves the files in a changed state.

Comment: Hmm, I tried, didn't do what I wanted. So I have this history `c1 -> c2 (pr-35)`. I've checked out `c1`. No local changes. Then I run `git checkout c1 && git merge --no-commit pr-35`. Still don't see local changes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you kindly edit you original post and provide your full git log and the git commands you provided as clear as possibile?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to look for a way to change the active commit

If you want to preserve the original branch, you just have to create a local branch :

```
git checkout -b max/review/35 PR-35
git reset --soft $(git merge-base master PR-35)
```